# Is it possible to run different mail servers on one server? eg. MailEnable and Kerio mail server

Tags: email, performance

i have just boought kerio mail server and i want to install it together with my current mail server MailEnable. I want to monitor kerio performance before i stop using the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but the mail servers would have to listen on different ports.  If it is a public facing mail server, it would be impossible to do as they would both need to listen on port 25 and 110.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or different ip addresses